# Problem Glut lib work in MS VIsual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opengl, glut

I want to run an openGL program in MS Visual Studio 2010, but it gave me the error "The glut32.dll is missing on your computer. Reinstall the program to fix the problem." I already put the glut32.dll in C:\windows\system32. Do I really need to reinstall MSVS10?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Are you running this on the 64-bit version of Windows?  Then copy the DLL to c:\windows\syswow64.  Or better yet, in the same directory as your EXE so you don't mess with the operating system directories.

Comment: Just figured that out. Thanks!